# How to handle that Firestore returns document items in inconsistent order

Tags: python, pandas, firebase, dataframe, google-cloud-firestore

Assume that I have the following table stored in a Firestore collection:

```
AAA BBB CCC
6   1   15
3   19  83
100 4   2
```

I would like to read the entire collection and convert it to a Pandas dataframe in Python. I tried it with the following code piece:

```
cred = credentials.Certificate(serviceAccountKeyJson)
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, databaseURL)
db = firestore.client()

col_ref = db.collection(collection_name)

docs = col_ref.stream()

rows_list = []
for doc in docs:
    column_name_list = list(doc.to_dict().keys())
    values_list = list(doc.to_dict().values())
    rows_list.append(values_list)

col_data_df = pd.DataFrame(rows_list, columns=column_name_list)
```

It works but when I save the `col_data_df` into a csv file, the content appears to be like to following:

```
AAA BBB CCC
15  1   6
3   83  19
100 4   2
```

I do know that each document in the collection has identical fields (I mean "field names") in each document. But I have the challenge that I do not know the name of these fields in advance!
I chose the ugly way of assigning field names to `column_name_list` in the `for` loop.
But it appears to be the case that order of fields vary at each step in the for loop.

For instance, the first row is supposed to be "6 1 15" but I see "15 1 6" in the csv file.

How can I read the collection data and save it in a Pandas dataframe (with Python) without knowing field names of the documents in advance?

Answer (score 0):

The following code seems to solve this problem:

```
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import firestore

db = firestore.Client()
users = list(db.collection(u'users').stream())

users_dict = list(map(lambda x: x.to_dict(), users))
df = pd.DataFrame(users_dict)
```

I found it here:
https://gist.github.com/romicofre/ee80100b62b5fdbed42218e8239df94e

Any other methods/solutions are more than welcome!